# read pipe input from keyboard

Tags: bash, pipe

This is very basic, sorry if this is a duplicate, but search results give me something opposite.

I want to paste lines as an input to a pipe. How can I do it?

For example I want to use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18141152/2361465 to sum a line of numbers. I could save my numbers into a file and do

```
cat numbers.txt | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

But my numbers are in the clipboard. Or they are in my head and I want to enter them manually. How do I feed them as the input without saving to a file?

I don't want the shell to read the Ubuntu clipboard, I want some command `???` that after execution waits for the input (with some way of indicating its end) and then passes it to the pipe.

```
??? | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything else - just type

```
paste -sd+ | bc
```

then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after which you can type or paste the numbers (separated by newlines), ending your input with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

```
$ paste -sd+ | bc
1.23
4.56
7.89
13.68
```

Alternatively, use a *here document*

```
$ paste -sd+ <<EOF | bc
> 1.23
> 4.56
> 7.89
> EOF
13.68
```

Comment: More generally, you can use `cat <<EOF | ...` and then type the input and end it with `EOF` on it's own line (EOF is by convention, could be any other string).